# Faker generate english sentences in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker

While using Faker with rails, it generates sentences in some other language. I want them to be generated in English. What kind of settings do I need to change to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs say

> Just set Faker::Config.locale to the locale you want, and Faker will take care of the rest.

https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/README.md

https://github.com/stympy/faker/tree/master/lib/locales

```
Faker::Config.locale = :en
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the quick reply. When I write this, it shows error as follows. 
"uninitialized constant Faker::Config". This also seems to be the docs for Perl Faker. Or am I missing something trivial?

Comment: Same docs http://rubydoc.info/github/stympy/faker/master/frames make sure you require faker

Comment: or write a faker.rb initializer

Comment: I have indded used the 'require 'faker''. When I use Faker::Name.name, it works fine. When I use Faker::Config.locale = :en, it gives the error uninitialized constant.

Comment: The problem was due to my using oldr version of Faker. thank you very much for your help.